# How to disable Serverside for search DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, datatable, datatables

I'm using DataTables with serverside to get my data but i want to have a search field by default.

But the field search use the serverside and i want to disable it only for the search field

This is my code but it calls the serverside

```
$('#data-table').on('search.dt', function() {
    var value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

JS file :

```
    processing: false,
    serverSide: true,
    searching: true,
    dom: '<"top"<"pull-right"f><"col-md-3"l><"col-md-offset-1 col-md-2"T>>t<"bottom"<"pull-right"p><"pull-left"i>>',
    ajax: opts.ajaxUrl,
    bfilter: true,
    columnDefs: opts.columns.map(function(column){
        return {
            targets : column.targets,
            data : column.data,
            orderable : column.orderable,
            render : getRendering(column.dataType, column.dataFunc ? column.dataFunc : null)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: set server processing = on , something like that is used for server processing,remove that, is this jquery datatable

Comment: I've edit my question to show you my config of dataTables because i didn't get what you meant by serverProcessing

Comment: serverSide: true, is making it search everytime from the server, remove this

Comment: all the data will be loaded at once,

Comment: I'm using the serverside for an other input that's why i've serverside: true

And that's why i'm trying to find a way to disable serverside only to the search field

But maybe isn't possible ?

Comment: did you find any solution?